# Copy a struct inside a byte buffer

Tags: c++, byte, buffer, memcpy, bytebuffer

I have the following struct:

```
struct sample {
  uint8_t four;
  bool    b;
  uint8_t two;
};
```

In order to send a udp packet, I need to pack these values into a single byte:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|     four      | 0 | b |  two  |
+---------------+---+---+-------+
```

What's the best way to copy struct values in this byte? I check the precondition before doing it so no data should be lost in copying `uint8_t` values into less space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just use a function:

```
uint8_t pack( const sample &s )
{
    return ( s.four & 0xF ) | ( s.b << 5 ) | ( ( s.two & 3 ) << 6 );
}
```

as you said that data range is checked you may simplify that to:

```
    return s.four | ( s.b << 5 ) | ( s.two << 6 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is not portable anyways, you might as well just use bit-fields here:

```
struct sample {
  uint8_t four:4;
  bool    empty:1;   
  bool    b:1;
  uint8_t two:2;
};
```

I am no fan of bit fields,  but they seem to be  applicable in your case.

Comment: Shouldn't `empty` come before `b`?

Comment: Why is not portable?

Comment: because you are going to entity-serialize uint8_t, and that is not portable.

Answer (score 0):

Your bit order is shown in a...unique way.  Usually when we express values in binary, lower bits are shown on the right.  So long as you are packing and unpacking the data, you can choose your bit order.  Watch out for network order vs system order though.  While the bit-order-within-bytes are the same on every platform, the byte-order-in-word can change.

You have to know your application to determine if packing/unpacking are worth the effort.  More computing on each side and depending on the intervals between UDP packets and how many data are packed into each UDP packet, it might not be worth it.  If you're just trying to save data for a cellular application, well, thank you :@)

I always avoid shifting booleans due to platform/compiler paranoia.  Could use something like s.b?32:0 instead.

Comment: I'm trying to create CIGI packets, and the standard have a lots of packets built in this way...

Comment: Sorry, bit of a brain lapse.  Networking packets are always written this way